# PHP image script doesn't work via $.post

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script that first creates a base64 image string and updates a form with that string...

```
<form method="post" action="/process.php">
 <input type="hidden" id="base64image" name="myimage" value="***base64 string gets updated here***" /> 
 <input type="submit" value="Create Rotated Image" />
</form>
```

It then posts to a php script which rotates it 90 degree's, retains transparency, and saves it as a png on the server.

process.php...

```
<?php
$data = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,","",$_POST["myimage"]);;
$data = base64_decode($data);
$degrees = 90;
$name = 'plate';
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
header('Content-Type: image/png');  
imagealphablending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
$rotation = imagerotate($im, $degrees, imageColorAllocateAlpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($rotation, false);
imagesavealpha($rotation, true);
imagepng($rotation);
$save = "* / root / my / image / directory / * image.png";
imagepng($rotation, $save);
imagedestroy($rotation);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

So far so good, that all works fine, it rotates and saves to the server and show that image in the browser.

Though now I want to post to this same script, but run it in the background without refreshing the page.

So I try this...

```
<form method="post" action="/process.php">
 <input type="hidden" id="base64image" name="myimage" value="" /> 
 <input type="submit" value="Create Rotated Image"     onclick="postimage();" />
</form>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var mybase64image = $('#base64image').val();
 function postimage() {
 $.post("/process.php", {myimage:mybase64image});
 };
 });
</script>
```

But this no longer saves the image to the server, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what code do you have here: `***base64 string gets updated here***`?

Comment: You need to prevent the default form submit.

Comment: increase the size of the post request body

Comment: I've set the post_max_size in php.ini to 300M, that what you meant? No change to the outcome, was previously set to 150M.

Comment: As said @charlietfl, try to write your function like this :
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
}

Comment: I think its a jquery problem add above your code '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>'

Comment: perfect it was $("#myform").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); } , thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed description of **But this no longer saves the image to the server** would help (e.g. your js console output or network protocol - "hit F12" in your browser).

As @charlietfl suggests I guess

```
<input type="submit"...>
```

submits your form by default. Try

```
<input type="button"...>
```

Comment: I can't post the whole base64 string, it's over 143,000 characters and stackoverflow only allows 30,000 charcters...

Comment: It's basically structured like... data:image/png;base64,a load of characters/numbers

Comment: I guess the concrete image data is not relevant here. What I am trying to figure out is the question if your browser does send anything at all via network. Please use the comments and have a look at the comment of A. Rossi above, too.